# Wordpress 500 internal server error after changing permission

Tags: php, wordpress

I changed my directory permission to 755. After that my wordpress home page goes blank and my network shows 500 internal server error. But my admin panel is working fine. My wp-admin goes to the admin panel and post edits can be made. But my front end completely fails to load.

Comment: up voted for , so other can easily view your question , they can give better answer than me

Comment: what is your permission of index.php ??

Comment: @Drudge 775 permission. Is it a permission issue?

Comment: What shows up in your server error log?

Comment: Also, what directory, and did you do it recursively?

Comment: @Matt Yes I did it recursively. As iam a beggiener in wordpress i have not set up error log. I saw one now and I was going to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cpanel, the files permission should be `0644` and folder permission should be `0755`. You are getting the error because your index.php permission is `0755`. To set correct permissions you need to use these commands:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *          # Let apache be owner
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # Change directory permissions rwxr-xr-x
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # Change file permissions rw-r--r--
```

you can visit [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) if you want to explore more .

Comment: so i have to run this command at the root or inside the project directory

Comment: inside your project folder .

Comment: is your index.php file has 0644 permission now?? Also, check the error log in error_log file .

Comment: yes index.php is in 644 permission and my error log does not have anything

Comment: i think now you should  to start to debug then mate . Just start with echo "test" in your index.php file and see up to where you can see test in your browser  .

Comment: I tried putting an echo "test"; exit(); in index.php first line before the get header but nothing comes

Comment: ya i too think the headers may be a problem.

Comment: then start to debug header file

Comment: @Drudge I found this one in my error.log file apache
"because search permissions are missing on a component of the path"

Comment: chcon -R --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t wp-content/ try this command now .

Comment: Iam on ubuntu and the command gives me "can't apply partial context to unlabeled file"

Comment: Everything was working fine until i changed the permission to 777 for some editing.

Comment: what is the permission of htaccess  ??

Comment: @Drudge I figured out the problem. It was with the template header as you had suggested. My collegue accedently moved a social wrapper into the navbar and something went wrong there. Since i had a backup of the files I was able to redo things easily. Thanks for the help